# Getting the users save as path from excel.application after giving them control

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I get the saved file path from an `Excel.Application` object after showing the object and giving the user control?

I don't know that it's important, but I need this information because I want to write this path to registry so the app knows where to go for searching or future editing. If the file does not exist or my program has no location provided, then I want to start creating one with the default headings and allow them to edit and save as with excel.

The main function of the program is to read the excel file for search values and populate form controls. This feature is file maintenance / error handling.

My current code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim misVal As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value
```

Here I tried to make the user save the file somewhere before editing, but excel still asks them to save as when closing.

```
xlApp = New Excel.Application
Dim file As String = xlApp.GetSaveAsFilename()

xlApp = New Excel.Application(file)
```

Showing the workbook works fine, I'm just stuck on how to retrieve the path the user saved to after they close the showing interface.

```
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misVal)
xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets("sheet1")
xlSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Group #"

xlApp.DefaultSaveFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12

xlApp.UserControl = True
xlApp.Visible = True
```

Thanks, Boom

EDIT:

Henderso's answer is basically what I ended up doing.

```
xlApp = New Excel.Application
Dim file As String = xlApp.GetSaveAsFilename()
' make changes to the book
xlBook.SaveAs(file)
xlApp = New Excel.Application(file)
```

After this I kept getting the prompt from excel to save as when the user closed the window. using `xlBook.Saved = True` fixed this. I wanted the user to select a location for the file to be and then have the program "auto save" when closing so I needed to also add an event handler

```
AddHandler xlBook.BeforeClose, AddressOf auto_save
```

where auto_save is the name of a sub I defined to do the work of the handler `xlBook.save()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create a new book, and prompt for new file name.  To the user, they will first get the save as prompt, then the new WB is shown.  Flname contains the full path of the save as file:

```
Set NewWkbk = Workbooks.Add
Flname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Enter Path for new file..")
NewWkbk.SaveAs (Flname)
```

Note, the GetSaveAsFilename filter is specifying .xlsx filetype.   You may need to adjust this is you want .xls or .xlsm